# Firefox SQLite Manager cannot access Xcode iPhone simulator SQLite DB Directory

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have a question regarding opening SQLite database from SQLite Manager extention of Firefox. I use SQLite database for my iOS app development and always use SQLite Manager to load the database for the app runs on iPhone emulator (The file is under /users/myUserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/MyAppGUID/Documents directory ). It worked fine since last week.

I suddenly found if I choose "Connect Database" from SQLite Manager menu, I couldn't find the /users/myUserName/Library directory anymore. I can still access the directory from Finder, I can still see the database file from Finder, and if I copy the db file to another directory, I can open it with SQLite Manager for no problem. However it is quite annoying that I couldn't open the database directly.

Anybody got the same problem before?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be related to the fact that the library folder is hidden by default on mac os Lion ? not sure if thats what your using but if so check out:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110704093233123

Comment: It was a hidden folder since day one, and I could access to it through sqlite manager. Still not sure why I couldn't do it now, but make the folder not hidden definitely solve the problem. And thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I used this tip to reveal the hidden files in OS X

http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/os-x/quick-tip-revealing-hidden-files-in-os-x/

Then I added the hidden Library directory to my Finder Favorites and when I go into SQLite Manager in Firefox, I can drill down to the app's sqlite file.